# String var not working in loop through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I need to loop through a series of values from a json array.  I can explicitly name the object I want to sum but when I pass it a string parameter it won't work.

My code below:

```
var tot = 0
var category = "arson_15"
for(var i = 0; i < dc_nbh.features.length; i++) {

    tot = tot + Number(dc_map.features[i].properties.category);
}
 console.log(tot);
```

This returns "NaN" but when I change it to the code below it summs the values correctly:

```
var tot = 0

for(var i = 0; i < dc_nbh.features.length; i++) {

    tot = tot + Number(dc_map.features[i].properties.arson_15);
}
 console.log(tot);
```

why can't I pass a string var to the loop?

Comment: `dc_map.features[i].properties[category]`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: For future reference, have you checked what the value of `dc_map.features[i].properties.category` is? This is a very common kind of bug in JS so understanding how to debug it is very beneficial.